# Why is bootstrap 4 adding an extra <td> tag here?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap with php to complete a coding exercise. The problem asks to create a table with city populations. For some reason the bottom of my table outputs an additional `<td>` tag that I cannot explain. I know its there via inspecting the source.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<?php  

$cities = array( 
    'ny' => 8175133,
    'la' => 3792621, 
    'chi' => 2695598, 
    'hou' => 2100263, 
    'phi' => 1526006, 
    'pho' => 1445632, 
    'sa' => 1327407, 
    'sd' => 1307402, 
    'dal' => 1197816, 
    'sj' => 945942 
            );
$tot_pop = array_sum($cities);
print "<div class='container'><table class='table'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope='col'>Cities</th>
<th scope='col'>Population</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

foreach($cities as $stadt => $pop) {
print "<tbody>
<tr>
<td>$stadt</td>
<td>$pop</td>     
</tr>";

}

print "
<tr>
<td>Total Pop<td>
<td>";
echo $tot_pop;
"</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
</div>";
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE9KK.jpg)

Comment: Just replace <td>Total Pop<td> to <td>Total Pop</td> because td is not closed after Total Pop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap isn't adding an extra `TD`, the PHP code is. The `<tbody>` shouldn't be inside the cities loop, it should be before.

The `<td>Total Pop<td>` doesn't have a proper closing tag (`</td>`), but instead opens another `<td>`.

Comment: Yes i removed my comment from your answer and add in question.